# Spring-Shiro Integration -- HTML page

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, shiro

I have integrated my Spring MVC application Shiro for security reasons.

My all urls are working fine, but i have few html pages which can be directly accessed without being hit on my controllers.

How can i protect those pages, meaning if user is not logged in to application, and tries to **open html page**, he should be redirected to login page.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

**Application url**

> http://ip:port - works fine, redirects to login page
>
> http://ip:port/html/ - opens html pages
>
> How can i protect this.

Answer (score 0):

I would make whatever page that redirect after the login page the default page.

In your controller, protect that page with `@Secured("USER_ROLE")` annotation at method level to a user role of a regular user. In fact, I would do that with every page.

The user should be redirected back to the login page, the go to the page they tried to reach.

Comment: I used `USER_ROLE` as an example. It can be whatever you use as roles

Comment: You did not understood my question

Comment: Okay. Please tell me where I misunderstood

Comment: how can i add spring controller for my html page

Comment: You can't just convert them to jsp?

Comment: Here's a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611896/spring-mvc-controller-return-html

Comment: let me try, jsp i cannot convert, it is all integrated with angular. :)